# Relations while updating entity in Symfony2 - one-to-one and one-to-many doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine

I've a problem with updating an entity(it is inversed side) in form, while the entity is properly updated with all the data, the related to it other entities are not, i.e in database their column referencing the "main" entity remain null or the data remain untouched.

Here is the code:

```
class Offer
{
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="DealOption", mappedBy="offer", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $dealOptions;

/**
 * @var Event
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="offer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $event;
}


class DealOption
{
/**
 * @var Offer
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Offer", inversedBy="dealOptions")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $offer;
}


class Event
{
/**
 * @var Offer
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Offer", mappedBy="event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $offer;
```

And the update action:

```
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Offer')->find($id);
    if (!$entity) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Offer.');
    }

    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
    $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {

        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('offer'));
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

According to my research and reading similiar problems with documentation it should work as is, however it doesn't, i suspect some basic misunderstanding on my part of how these relations should behave, work and be defined, but to this moment no bueno and no succes.
I'd be grateful for any advice.

Edit - OfferFormBuilder:

```
class OfferType extends AbstractType
{
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('dealOptions')
        ->add('title')
        ->add('event')
        ->add('division')
    ;
}
```

Comment: Are you using subforms for the DealOption and Event entities? Could you post your form definition code?

Comment: I edited the question and added OfferType (Form Builder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The null indicates that you are not cross referencing the objects properly.  It's a very common mistake.

```
class Offer {
  public function setEvent($event) {
    $this->event = $event;
    $event->setOffer($this); // *** This is what you are probably missing.
```

Do the same for deals as well.

Comment: Thank you, you were correct, this aforementioned statement was missing in setEvent and setDealOption, however after adding it and running a test update again it still doesnt update the offer_id column. 
In the meantime I also managed to simply loop through related deals and set them in the updateAction, and it works partly, because it just adds newly added data to offer_id, not replacing them. :)
edited in updateAction:
    `if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            foreach($entity->getDealOptions() as $dealOpt){
                $entity->setDealOptions($dealOpt);
            }`

Comment: You really don't want to have to do this sort of loop.  Since it is a one to many relation then I would expect you would have a Offer::addDeal method.  It's important to get the relations right otherwise you will have lot's of other problems down stream.

Comment: That's right, it should work without such additional ad-hoc stuff, but still - without it, and after updating offer (i.e changing deals, event) it doesn't update the referenced id_offer columns.