# One to One relation in Doctrine updates only one field - Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

it is a follow-up to my previous post [Relations while updating entity in Symfony2 - one-to-one and one-to-many doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255466/relations-while-updating-entity-in-symfony2-one-to-one-and-one-to-many-doesnt)

While I've managed to solve the issue with One-to-Many, although by some dirty fix in the Controller, the same isn't working with One-to-One, where i get the following error:
    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '16' for key 'UNIQ_3BAE0AA753C674EE'

The Code:

```
    Class Offer {
/**
 * @var Event
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Event", inversedBy="offer")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="event_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $event;
}

    Class Event {
/**
 * @var Offer
 *
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Offer", mappedBy="event")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="offer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $offer;
}
```

Plus, on the last post it has been suggested to me to add following code on the setEvent (precisely the "$event->setOffer($this);" part:

```
/**
 * Set event
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Event $event
 * @return Offer
 */
public function setEvent(\AppBundle\Entity\Event $event)
{
    $this->event = $event;
    $event->setOffer($this);

    return $this;
}
```

After update it only fills with correct data the event_id in Offer table, or after tinkering with the code i get the error about duplicate entry SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '16' for key 'UNIQ_3BAE0AA753C674EE'

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I'd be grateful for any feedback.

UPDATE & SOLUTION (code added to updateAction in OfferController):

```
$oldEvent = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')->findOneBy(array("offer"=>$entity));
 if ($oldEvent != NULL) {
 $oldEvent->removeOffer(); 
 $em->persist($oldEvent); 
 } $newEvent = $entity->getEvent(); 

 $entity->setEvent($newEvent);
```

Not a cleanset way, rather a quick fix but works fine, but still im interested what has happened that it doesn't work Out-of-the-Box in the ORM Doctrine way.

Comment: Not sure if this might be the problem but the JoinColumn annotation should only be present in the "owning" side (`Offer`in this case)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, you're correct - the mentioned annotation is unnecessary, however after deleting it and running doctrine:schema:update, the problem remains as described above "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: (...)"
I'm running out of ideas what might be broken.

Comment: Anyway - it does not work as it should, so I had to do with a not-so-pretty solution added to the controller, that is:

    `$oldEvent = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Event')->findOneBy(array("offer"=>$entity));

            if ($oldEvent != NULL) {
                $oldEvent->removeOffer();
                $em->persist($oldEvent);
            }

            $newEvent = $entity->getEvent();
            $entity->setEvent($newEvent);`

It works fine as a quick fix, In the free time I'll try again with the standard Doctrin ORM one more time.

Answer (score 1):

[In the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#association-updates-owning-side-and-inverse-side) you can read that:

> Doctrine will only check the owning side of an association for changes.

And [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts) in detail:

> To fully understand this, remember how bidirectional associations are maintained in the object world. There are 2 references on each side of the association and these 2 references both represent the same association but can change independently of one another. Of course, in a correct application the semantics of the bidirectional association are properly maintained by the application developer (**that’s his responsibility**). Doctrine needs to know which of these two in-memory references is the one that should be persisted and which not. This is what the owning/inverse concept is mainly used for.

Your `setEvent` method does exactly what it is supposed to do. It also takes care of the inverse side of the relationship. 
 
But it also means you have to manage your entity from the owning side.
`Offer` is the owning side of the relationship so I would suggest calling persist on the `$offer` instead of on the `$event`.

```
$offer->setEvent($event);
$em->persist($offer);
```